# Undefined columns selected while doing a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 13 data frames with the same parameters. For each data frame, I want to extract the column `P.Value` (only the rows which are smaller than 0.05) and add it to a new vector. Instead of writing the same code 13 times, I want to do a for loop:

```
for (i in (1:13)) {
  
  MyGenes[i] = df[i][df[i]$P.Value < 0.05,]
  
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i) : undefined columns selected
```

What am I doing wrong? the names of the data frames are `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, and so on. At the end I want `MyGenes1`, `MyGenes2` .... `MyGenes13`.

Comment: By doing `df[i]` you are accessing the "df" dataframe, which has both rows and columns, so it is expecting two dimensions, `df[i,j]`. In order to loop through your dataframes you should create a list of dataframes and then you can use `list[[i]]` to select each of the datasets.

Comment: Also, if you have them as a lisit you could probably use `lapply` and avoid creating a loop.

Comment: @wernor could you please help with the code? how do I perform the `lapply` function in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want with

```r
for (i in 1:13) {
  
  assign(paste0('MyGenes', i), 
         subset(get(paste0('df', i)), P.Value < 0.05))
}
```

However, working with a list of data frames (as suggested by wernor) would be more convenient:

```r
# sample data
df.list <- list(data.frame(x=1:5, P.Value=seq(0, .2, length.out=5)),
                data.frame(x=3:7, P.Value=seq(0, .1, length.out=5)))

MyGenes <- lapply(df.list, subset, P.Value < 0.05)
```